# Add 2 rows between existing rows

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to add 2 rows between the row 14 and 15.

For that I am using:

```
sheet.shiftRows(14, 15, rowToBeAdd);
```

But instead of adding these two rows, my application is expading the row 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static void addRow(int amount, int currentRow) throws Exception {
    sheet.shiftRows(currentRow, sheet.getLastRowNum(), amount);
}
```

The method noted above might shed some light on your question. The params are Amount & currrent row. Not Currentrow and end row.

Comment: Invexity, instead of setting the row 14 as the first parameter, I set the row 15. And I used the sheet.getLastRowNum() as the second parameter.